# I want to write a sqlcmd script that pulls data from a database and then manipulates that data

Tags: sql, ssms, sqlcmd

I'm trying to find examples of sqlcmd script files that will run a select statement, and return those values internal to the script and place them in a variable.  I then want to iterate over those returned values, run some if statements on those returned values, and then run some sql insert statements.  I'm using Sql Server Managment Studio, so I thought I could run some scripts in the sqlcmd mode of the Query Editor.  Maybe there's a better way to do it, but that seemed like a good solution.

I've looked on the Microsoft website for sqlcmd and T-SQL examples that might help.  I've also done general searches of the web, but all the examples that come up are too simplistic, and weren't helpful. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify a little exactly what problem you're trying to solve? Is the issue that you don't know how to iterate over a set of results in T-SQL, or that you need assistance with using SQLCMD to execute some T-SQL, or both?

Comment: I want to basically take out two already existing varchar columns in a table in my database, and replace them with one int column.  The int column with be a foreign key to a new lookup table replacing the two already existing columns.  I've already created the new column in the table for the int value as nullable.  So I want to select every row currently in the table, check the values of the varchar's that are in there, and then look up the associated value in the lookup table, and then populate that value in the current table.  Then delete the varchar columns.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: The biggest part of the problem I'm having is putting the results of a query into an array or list of some sort, and then looping through those rows.  It's seems none of the examples I've seen have done that.

Comment: I've added an answer based on the assumption that your lookup table is already populated with values. If this is not the case, let me know and I can edit to show how the lookup table could be generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I understand your starting position:

```
create table #data
(
    id int,
    column1 varchar(100),
    column2 varchar(100),
    newcolumn int
)

create table #lookup
(
    id int,
    column1 varchar(100),
    column2 varchar(100)
)

insert into #data
values 
(1, 'black', 'duck', NULL),
(2, 'white', 'panda', NULL),
(3, 'yellow', 'dog', NULL),
(4, 'orange', 'cat', NULL),
(5, 'blue', 'lemur', NULL)

insert into #lookup
values
(1, 'white', 'panda'),
(2, 'orange', 'cat'),
(3, 'black', 'duck'),
(4, 'blue', 'lemur'),
(5, 'yellow', 'dog')

select * from #data
select * from #lookup
```

Output:

```
select * from #data
/------------------------------------\
| id | column1 | column2 | newcolumn |
|----|---------|---------|-----------|
| 1  | black   | duck    | NULL      |
| 2  | white   | panda   | NULL      |
| 3  | yellow  | dog     | NULL      |
| 4  | orange  | cat     | NULL      |
| 5  | blue    | lemur   | NULL      |
\------------------------------------/

select * from #lookup
/------------------------\
| id | column1 | column2 |
|----|---------|---------|
| 1  | white   | panda   |
| 2  | orange  | cat     |
| 3  | black   | duck    |
| 4  | blue    | lemur   |
| 5  | yellow  | dog     |
\------------------------/
```

From this starting point, you can achieve what you are asking for as follows:

```
update d set d.newcolumn = l.id
from #data d
left join #lookup l on d.column1 = l.column1 and d.column2 = l.column2

alter table #data
drop column column1, column2
```

This will leave the tables in the desired state, with the varchar values moved out into the lookup table:

```
select * from #data
/----------------\
| id | newcolumn |
|----|-----------|
| 1  |     3     |
| 2  |     1     |
| 3  |     5     |
| 4  |     2     |
| 5  |     4     |
\----------------/

select * from #lookup
/------------------------\
| id | column1 | column2 |
|----|---------|---------|
| 1  | white   | panda   |
| 2  | orange  | cat     |
| 3  | black   | duck    |
| 4  | blue    | lemur   |
| 5  | yellow  | dog     |
\------------------------/
```

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct.  This is exactly right.  This is awesome.  I didn't think to use the join that way.  I've always joined on just one column.  Is the # of the #data and #lookup simply part of the name of the table, or is there more meaning to that symbol?

Comment: BTW, is there any easy way to loop through rows of a multi row return from say a select statement that you know of?

Comment: The table names being  prefixed with `#` signifies that they are temp tables, I just used temp tables for the purposes of this demo - you’d be working with you real tables of course.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to step sequentially through a results set and perform some operation on each row in turn, you’ll want to read up on Cursors in SQL to learn more. Be aware though, usually if you can achieve your desired outcome with a set-based solution like I’ve suggested here, it’s a better idea than doing anything with a Cursor or Loop.

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, please feel free to upvote and accept it. Have a great day!